# pre-selection of fields with ajax for select2

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

When I try to pre-select the value with ajax everything except the shown value is working. 
Does anyone know where I've made the mistake?

I call the `pre_select()` function for each `<select>`.
When I look in to the code, everything is OK, but the label on the page is showing me the `ID` instead of `myTitle`. After submitting the form, the data is also ok! I need only the right label...

```
function pre_select(pre_id, query_id) { //my ID of selection, the query
    var mySelect = $('#form_my_id'+pre_id);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        dataType:'json',
        url: '?search&id='+query_id
    }).then(function (data) {
        var option = new Option(data.myTitle, data.id, true, true);
        mySelect.append(option).trigger('change');
        mySelect.trigger({
            type: 'select2:select',
            params: {
                data: data
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Here is the HTML output

```
<select name="form_select[]" class="form-control select2bs4 select2-hidden-accessible" id="form_my_id1" width="100%" required="" data-select2-id="form_stok_id1" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
    <option value="1" selected="" data-select2-id="5">The Title Of Product</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

This function has done my job :-)

```
function pre_select(pre_id, query_id) { //my ID of selection, the query
    var mySelect = $('#form_my_id'+pre_id);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        dataType:'json',
        url: '?search&id='+query_id
    }).then(function (data) {
        mySelect.select2("trigger", "select", {
            data: data
        });
    });
}
```